# I Want to show the image in Decoration Image of a container

Tags: flutter, dart

I Want to show the image (image1) in Decoration Image of a container.

```
InkWell(
                          onTap: (() async {
                            image1 = (await _picker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.gallery));
                          }),
                          child: Container(
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                // Decoration image in here (image1) 
                              ),
                              
                        ),
```

Comment: does adding setState after getting image1 solves your issue?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you show me how?

Comment: `image1 = (await _picker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.gallery)); setState((){})`

Comment: thanks but i meant show me how to implement in the container's decoration image.. @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  a nullable variable for decoration image on state class. Also container decoration image can take null.

```dart
  DecorationImage? decorationImage;
```

Make sure to import

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    XFile? image1 =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        
    if (image1 == null) {
      debugPrint("got null");
      return;
    }
    final image = Image.memory(await image1.readAsBytes());
    decorationImage = DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      image: image.image,
    );
    setState(() {});
  },
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4 - 25,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue.shade900,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      image: decorationImage,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (image1 != null) ...{
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image:  FileImage(
                File(image1!.path),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      }else...{
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('empty_image_path.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      }
```

Comment: but before user add any image in there it will be null, hence error.  @Abdullah Ali

Comment: make `image1` nullable

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: you need to put this code in setState
   image1 = (await _picker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.gallery));